# Can a filtered index still be used if the condition is false?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server, I can create a filtered index so that only one child record *per parent record* can have `IsPrimary = 1`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_Child_IsPrimary 
    ON dbo.Child(ParentId, IsPrimary) 
    WHERE IsPrimary = 1;
```

Can this index be used to when querying to find **all** children of a given parent or does it only apply to children with `IsPrimary = 1`?

In other words, do I need to have an additional index just for the foreign key `ParentId`?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Child_ParentId]
    ON dbo.Child(ParentId ASC);
```

I'm unsure since creating an index such as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Child_ParentId]
    ON dbo.Child(ParentId ASC, SomeOtherColumn ASC);
```

Can still be used when searching by `ParentId` as far as I understand, so I'm not sure if filtered indexes have somewhat similar behavior.

Comment: The index will only contain the rows that match the predicate. It wouldn't be very effective if it included all rows. It seems redundant to include `IsPrimary` in the key and *also* filter on it - you know that all rows in the index will have `IsPrimary = 1`. If you want to use the index also for queries that return all children, then you should not have the filter IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I want, at most, one primary child record per parent, but as many non-primary child records as desired. Wouldn't removing the filter or removing `IsPrimary` from the index limit the number of non-primary children?

Comment: You asked: :"Can this index be used to when querying to find all children of a given parent" the answer is ***NO***. The filtered index will *only* contain rows where `IsPrimary = 1`. If you need an index to support queries for *all* children, and an index to enforce only one primary child exists, you need two indexes.